# Finding a subspace of orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, orthogonal-matrices

I would like some help solving this question

P is an orthogonal projection that is defined by:

$$P:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$$
$$P(v)=1/180\begin{pmatrix}144&72&0\\72&36&0\\ 0&0&180\end{pmatrix}·v$$
How do I find subspace $W$ so that $$P=P_w, \quad ?$$
I've searched everywhere online but i can't seem to find a solution to it.

Comment: What is $P_w$? You have defined only $P(v)$? And is $W=w$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Pw is the orthogonal projection on W. I'm not really sure what P(v) is supposed to mean really the question stated that without any explaination to what it is.

Comment: $P$ is the projection transformation of some subspace $W$ i.e. $P(v)$ is the projection of $v\in\Bbb R^3$ on $W$. You need to find $W$, which is nothing but the range-space of $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ the associated matrix.

We verify that $A^2=A$.

The null space of A is $\text{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}-10\\20\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$

The column space of A is $\text{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}4/5\\2/5\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$

They are orthogonal.

P is the orthogonal projection on $W=\text{span}\left\{(0,0,1),(4/5,2/5,0)\right\}$

Answer (score 0):

First, I checked and, yes, the determinant of that matrix is 0 so it does map R^3 onto a proper subspace of dimension 2, or 1.
Let $v= \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$ be a vector in $R^3$.

Then $Pv= \frac{1}{180}\begin{bmatrix}144 & 72 & 0 \\ 72 & 36 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 180 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}= \frac{1}{180}\begin{bmatrix}144x+ 72y \\ 72x+ 36y \\ 180z\end{bmatrix}$

If x= y= 0 and z= 1, that is $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ so that is one basis vector.

If x= z= 0 and y= 1, that is $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{72}{180} \\ \frac{36}{180} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{5} \\ \frac{1}{5} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  That is not a multiple of $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ so it is another basis vector.

We can now say that, since the maximum dimension of the subspace was 2, these two vectors form a basis.

If you were wondering, yes, we could also take y= z= 0 and x= 1 to get
$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{144}{180} \\ \frac{72}{180} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{5} \\ \frac{2}{5} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  But $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{5} \\ \frac{2}{5} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}= 2 \begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{5} \\ \frac{1}{5} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ so that is not an independent vector.